# setvar - Incorrect syntax near 'dbname'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sqlcmd

I've searched for the answer for this but all I can see is answers to "incorrect syntax near ':'" which is easily solved by turning on SQLCMD mode.

But once I've turned that on I get another error:

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2`

`Incorrect syntax near 'MyDatabaseName'.`

...with the following code:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDatabaseName"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "MyDatabaseName"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""


GO
:on error exit
GO
```

I am also curious why it says line 2 when the code is on line 16 (there are comments above what I posted there)

Comment: It says line 2, because it parses the code as the grammar is, not as your file/text contains it. It simply divides the code into understandable blocks and execute them.

Answer (score 1):

OK the answer turned out to be nothing to do with that code above.

Later on down, there was a statement

```
CREATE [$(DatabaseName)];
```

Obviously the variable is evaluated before the syntax is checked so this was translated into MyDatabaseName,

but of course it should have been

```
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)];
```

Changing it to this worked.